# Binary image type in C

Tags: c, image-processing, binary

If I want to create and work on a binary image in C, what data type should be set for the image pixels? Since a binary image pixel only has two values I am assuming I just need one bit for each pixel and thus I have to use the bit wise C functions, is this the correct (most efficient) way to do binary image processing in C?

If that is the case, how can I allocate space for the image? `malloc` only allocates space in units of bytes if I am not mistaking.

For clarification: I have a 32bit float image (with known size), I apply a threshold and would like to save the thresholding result as a binary so I can label the separate components.

Comment: If you have the image, don't you... already have the image?  In memory, I mean.  Or, at least, know its size?

Comment: Yes, I have an image, I apply a threshold and would like to save the result as binary to label segments.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Could you please re-open the question?  astroboy's clarification is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a single bit per pixel is most memory-efficient but least time-efficient, since accessing pixels requires bitwise operations.  If you wanted to do this, you would have to `malloc((numPixels + 7)/8)`, i.e. round up the allocation size to the nearest byte.

It would probably be a better balance of memory and space considerations to store the image as `char`s.  This is the internal representation for thresholded images in OpenCV, for example.

Comment: Thanks. By efficiency my main goal was time efficiency. I was thinking that bitwise operations are faster than byte operations, isn't that true?

Comment: @astroboy Storing the image as bits is significantly less time-efficient.  Processors don't have instructions to do instructions on single bits, so you have to convert the bit to a byte anyways.  In both cases, operating on a pixel requires fetching a byte from memory (same time for both), but in the bits case, you also need to use bitmasks and bitshifts to get the value of the pixel as a byte.

Comment: I think practically, 1" is correct.  But theoretically, working with bit data can be quite a bit faster as up to 8 or even 16 operations can occur at a time.  The practical problem is the fetching, dealing with edge effects, and the general problem that common (byte) operations would need to be hand-tooled via bit operations and lookup tables.

Comment: @Jim It's very true that, since many image processing operations operate on nearby pixels, it could be more efficient to operate on bit-images with a highly hand-crafted implementation.  I agree with your analysis of the drawbacks, though.